# How to right click on YouTube video for "stats for nerds" option using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, right-click

I'm developing a program which blocks YouTube ads & records the blocked Ad Video ID.

To do all of that we need to make our selenium program right click on the video to open the video menu & then select "stats for nerds". By doing so the HTML Elements for Ad Video ID & Video ID appear in the source code which then it can be used.

The main problem I'm facing is how to automatically right click for the video menu. Selenium is able to press left click on the video to pause it but not right click.

My Code: -

```
function handleSkipBtn() {

    if (skipBtn.length > 0) {

        //This Lines of code is used to get ad video ID. I just want to open stats of nerds here and then close it.

        var a = document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-sfn-cpn");
        if (a.length > 0) {
            var b = a[0].innerText;
            alert(b);
        }

        skipBtn[0].click();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to wait for the element to appear in DOM. You can use MutationObserver.

Comment: @wOxxOm It does not appear unless right click event is triggered on the video content window. That's why I want to right click automatically.

Comment: Use MutationObserver to wait for `document.querySelector('.ytp-menuitem:last-child')` then click() it.

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't understand. Waiting won't bring the element in DOM but right clicking on video for options does bring elements in DOM. I've tried alot to right click automatically in JavaScript but js has no inbuilt function to right click. It only has .click function.

Comment: Hmm... `movie_player.dispatchEvent(new Event('contextmenu'))`

Answer (score 0):

This will open the right-click menu for you:

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-contextmenu")[0].style.display = "block";');
```

And this will click the stats for nerds button:

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-menuitem")[6].click();');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  
My problem remains that this class "ytp-contextmenu" does not appear unless i manually right click. It is hidden in a sense.

Further, how do I initiate 'driver' so that it works on already open browser & YouTube video. Solutions on the internet tell us to intiate driver by assigning specific port etc...
But I am building a chrome extension that everyone can use. So assigning port solution doesn't work.

Waiting for your response!

Comment: I've to right click on "video-stream html5-main-video" html element so that "ytp-contextmenu" becomes visible. Currently i can not perform operations on it.

Comment: You can initialize 'driver' with `driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)`. Once that is set, you can make the right-click menu visible with `driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-contextmenu")[0].style.display = "block";');`.

Comment: If you need more help, I can help tomorrow